# Install rEFInd on separate partition (Errors)

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, dual-boot, efi

I am trying to install rEFInd a separate partition but have run into an error. I'm doing this because I want to install Ubuntu on my other partition (separate from my Mac and and rEFInd partition). Here's my diskutil list:

[image]

I run the command `./install.sh --alldrivers --ownhfs /dev/disk0s5` and get this output:

[image]

I don't know where to look for the error messages. The rEFInd partition is formatted as OS X Extended (Journaled). Once I get this working, I want the rEFInd partition to load up first when I boot my computer. It's not recognized as a startup partition right now.

Comment: rEFInd needs to be put on an EFI formatted partition, which is essentially FAT. Please make sure you capitalize the EFI part in rEFInd, as that's the proper name.

Comment: @IronCraftMan I formatted it as MS-DOS(FAT), but still get the same error.